# Passing vanilla JS object as prop to a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eventemitter

I have written a class to model messages that come into my application called message.js

In message.js, I have two classes defined; the Message class and another class called EventEmit. My Message class has a render function that needs to be able to pass an EventEmit object as a prop to a child component.

In the child component (main.js), I attempt to access the EventEmit object by:

```
    let eventemitter = this.props.eventemitter;
    eventemitter.on('someeventstring', somecallback());
```

When debugging, if I stop on the second line referenced above, I can enter 'eventemitter' and I am returned an object and I can see the .on() method.

However, when that line executes, I receive a 'eventemitter.on' is not a function error in the console. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Code below

Message.js

```
export class Message extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ...
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Index eventemitter = {EventEmitter} />
        );
    }
} 
export class EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
      this.events = {};
      this.on = this.on.bind(this);
      this.removeListener = this.removeListener.bind(this);
      this.emit = this.emit.bind(this);
    }
    on = (event, listener) => {
        if (typeof this.events[event] !== 'object') {
            this.events[event] = [];
        }
        this.events[event].push(listener);
        return () => this.removeListener(event, listener);
    }
    removeListener = (event, listener) => {
      if (typeof this.events[event] === 'object') {
          const idx = this.events[event].indexOf(listener);
          if (idx > -1) {
            this.events[event].splice(idx, 1);
          }
      }
    }
    emit = (event, ...args) => {
      if (typeof this.events[event] === 'object') {
        this.events[event].forEach(listener => listener.apply(this, args));
    }
}
```

index.js

```
componentDidMount() {

    let eventemitter = this.props.eventemitter;
    eventemitter.on('someeventstring', somecallback()); //<--Problem line

}
```

Comment: Create an object of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to call call method `on()` you need to instantiate the class. Try:

`<Index eventemitter={new EventEmitter()} />`

Comment: Dumb mistake. Thanks!